# Can Shatter destroy bones created by Wall of Bones?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e

Shatter spell specifically targets *non-magical objects*.

Wall of Bones, on the other hand, creates a wall of Bones that disappears after a certain time, unlike Wall of Stone which is an instantaneous spell. It seems to imply that those bones are magical.

I would think Shatter targeting stone wall created by Wall of Stone is totally valid, but how about bones from Wall of Bones? Those bones can be smashed, so I see no reason (except for RAW) it cannot be destroyed by Shatter. Maybe allowing a Fort save makes more sense? What would the DC be?

Answer (score 10):

## A [*shatter*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/shatter/) spell can't affect a [*wall of bones*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/wall-of-bone/) effect

The *shatter* spell says that it does one of three things: It either "creates a loud, ringing noise that breaks brittle, *non-magical* objects; sunders a single solid, *non-magical* object; or damages a crystalline creature" (emphases mine).

The effect created by a *wall of bones* spell is magical because the effect's on a [time duration](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#TOC-Duration): the magic ends when the spell's duration expires and, for example, even if the timer is still going a successful *dispel magic* spell will dispel a *wall of bones* effect prematurely, and the effect winks out in an area of antimagic. Hence a *wall of bones* effect isn't a valid target for any function of the *shatter* spell (especially not the last).

The [*wall of stone*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/wall-of-stone/) spell, on the other hand, has an [instantaneous duration](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#TOC-Duration): after the spell's resolved, the magic ends, but the spell's effect remain. And what remains is a totally normal nonmagical wall—a *dispel magic* spell can't dispel it, and it's unaffected by areas of antimagic.

Also, to be clear, the *shatter* spell typically can't affect a stone wall: a wall is usually neither a group of brittle objects nor a lone object. However, a GM may allow a *shatter* spell to target a [wall section](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/environment/dungeons#TOC-Walls).

Comment: May want to also indicate that a stone wall is probably far heavier an object than Shatter can affect given it's 10 lbs/caster level limitation.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that it's a necromancy spell as opposed to conjuration (creation)